# scala/liftweb serializing json

Tags: scala, lift

I am using net.liftweb parser for scala

I have a json like this

```
  {
  "k1":"v1",
  "k2":["v21", "v22", "v23"]
  }
```

k2 is an optional field, json might or might not have it. I extract this into a case class

case class MyCC (k1: String, k2: List[String])

When json is converted to case class, if k2 is not present then it is deserialized into empty list. The issue is while converting back to json, how could i make the parser not serialize this field if it is an empty list.

Comment: This sounds like precisely what `Option` is meant for.

Comment: @soong: u mean field k2 should be of type: Option[List[String]]. I dont think it is a good idea to use 2 continers (list , option)

Comment: Why not?  That's exactly what it is... I guess if you don't like it, you could just use an empty list, but the logic you'd write to handle it that way is precisely what `Option` already has in it.

Comment: I prefer `Nil: List[String]` instead of `None: Option[List[String]]` too. The extra layout is annoying for me. And you anyway have to be familiar with these serialization strategies when you deal with api requirements, elasticSearch indexes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should create [custom serializer](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serializing-non-supported-types). This should be fine for your case:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.write
class NilSerializer extends CustomSerializer[List[String]](format => ( {
    case JNothing => Nil
  }, {
    case Nil => JNothing
}))

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new NilSerializer
println(write(MyCC("key", Nil)))
>> {"k1":"key"}
```