# How to deserialize String array with embedded null using Jackson with Scala module?

Tags: scala, jackson, jackson-modules

I have the following Scala `case class`:

```
case class InteractionPersona(
    id: String,
    geo: Option[(Option[String], Option[String], Option[String])])
```

Using Jackson, when I serialize an instance of the class:

```
val persona = InteractionPersona("123", Some((Some("canada"), None, None)))
val json = mapper.writeValueAsString(persona)
```

I receive the following JSON:

```
{"id": "123", "geo": ["canada", null, null]}
```

which is a perfectly valid representation for my needs. During deserialization though, I receive `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of VALUE_NULL token`:

```
val actual = mapper.readValue(json, classOf[InteractionPersona])
```

Apparently, `null` is not an acceptable `String` value, but since I'm deserializing to a Scala `Option[String]`, `null` should be represented as a `None` value.

In [How to deserialize Jackson Json NULL String to Date with JsonFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123887/how-to-deserialize-jackson-json-null-string-to-date-with-jsonformat), @wassgren suggested using a converter using the `JsonDeserialize` annotation, and after reading documentation, I chose to use the `contentUsing` option:

```
case class InteractionPersona(
    id: String,
    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = classOf[GeoConverter])
    geo: Option[(Option[String], Option[String], Option[String])])

class GeoConverter extends JsonDeserializer[Option[(Option[String], Option[String], Option[String])]] {
    override def deserialize(jp: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Option[(Option[String], Option[String], Option[String])] = {
        throw new RuntimeException("tada")
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, that code does not raise the expected exception. Attempting to use a `contentConverter` also does not raise any exception:

```
@JsonDeserialize(contentConverter = classOf[GeoConverter])

class GeoConverter extends StdConverter[String, Option[String]] {
    override def convert(value: String): Option[String] = {
        throw new RuntimeException("tada")
    }
}
```

How can I read an array of String objects and accept or transform null values?

Comment: Using Jackson 2.3.5, because that is the most recent version with pre-built binaries for the Scala module for the 2.9.1 series of Scala.

Comment: Do you use DefaultScalaModule? https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala

Comment: There is an overkill: use json4s and write rules for your own serializer. (lik here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710814/scala-liftweb-serializing-json)

Comment: I do register the `DefautlScalaModule`.

Comment: I've used the DefaultScalaModule and I find that it doesn't handle null values (i.e. ones that are declared but have no value e.g.: foo:)                Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of NOT_AVAILABLE token